# NSKeyValueObservingOptions error on swift

Tags: ios, swift, observers

sometime when I call `ignoreFrameChanges` method I get this error:

> Cannot remove an observer, for the key path "frame" from <......>
>   because it is not registered as an observer.

How can I control before remove that observe, if there is any observe with frame name or not?

```
func watchFrameChanges() {

    addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New|NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial, context: nil)
}   

func ignoreFrameChanges() {

    removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame")    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you call ignoreFrameChanges method even when the class is not observing for 'frame'.

Would it be possible to use init and deinit to observe and remove observer ? That would make sure that you always observe and remove the observer when it gets released.

You could also use some variable to track the observation like some boolean value as such,

```
var isObserving = false

func watchFrameChanges() {
    isObserving = true
    addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame", options: NSKeyValueObservingOptions.New|NSKeyValueObservingOptions.Initial, context: nil)
}   

func ignoreFrameChanges() {
    if !isObserving { return }
    removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "frame")    
}
```

Comment: it is not a solitions. bro I tried that. same like you. but ı get same error. for the key path "frame" from <project.TableViewCell 0x153f4c00> because it is not registered as an observer.'

Comment: Ok, can you show more of your code. Where do you observe and where do you unobserve. More code would be useful to visualize the context.

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        
        (cell as!  TableViewCell).watchFrameChanges()
    }
    
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        
        (cell as!  TableViewCell).ignoreFrameChanges()
    }